# Mongoid ruby I'm trying to create a statement where we filter based on two criteria

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I'm trying to filter array so that field1 the output does not contain any entries where field1: true or (field2:true, field1: nil)

Does this statement work?

```
user.array.where(timestamp: time_window)
            .ne(
                {
                  $or => [
                          { field1: true },
                          { field2: true, field1: nil }
                         ]
                }
              )
```

Currently, I am getting all the entries meaning no filtering is occuring?

Comment: `ne` is a field-level operator. Your code probably generates a nonsensical `$ne` clause which means all documents would satisfy it. To perform logical or, use `or`.

Comment: If you want to use `$or`, do `.where('$or' => [...])`

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not have an expression-level $not operator, but it can be emulated with $and and $nor:

```
user.array.where(timestamp: time_window)
            .where(
                {
                  $nor => [
                          { field1: true },
                         ]
                }
              )
            .where(
                {
                  $nor => [
                          { field2: true, field1: nil }
                         ]
                }
              )
```

Comment: I am trying to reject the documents that have these attributes { field1: true },
                          { field2: true, field1: nil }. Is there like an opposite of where